# Defer Jquery Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, deferred

I would like to defer jQuery on wordpress in order to get a 100 page speed insight score, however once defered it breaks the jQuery on the website.

How can I do this

Comment: A google search shows this https://wpshout.com/make-site-faster-async-deferred-javascript-introducing-script_loader_tag/

Comment: This did not help, I have tried googling it hense why I came to stack overflow as my efforts proved futile